# iPhone best design for 70 different views?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, view

I am new to iPhone development... trying to figure out the best design for 70+ views.  Do I have 1 Navcontroller and 70 views or what?

I originally thought I would have about 10 XIBs each with their own NavController and views, but I haven't found anyone that seems to think this is correct or not.

I think I understand the iPhone does not handle the memory dealloc by itself so I am assuming that will be a bit choice on how to make this work.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to implement 70+ views means you have to use both the navigation controller as well as tabbar controller. Then only the user can easily access all the views. If you are using 1 navigation controller and 70+ views means it is very difficult for the user to view all the views.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to design your views graphically using Interface Builder (built into Xcode4 or separate app for Xcode 3 and prior), I would just have a UINavigationController in your first xib (one with the UIWindow).  You can then design each of your other views separately, in their own xib file and load them and push them onto the navigation stack as necessary.

Your understanding is correct; iOS does not support automatic garbage collection, although there is a pretty established paradigm of how to allocate and release memory as needed to avoid memory leaks.  70 views in an iPhone app is quite a bit, but it should be fine in theory, although I can see there being issues if the user has to drill down quite a ways in the hierarchy and each successive view eating up more memory.

Comment: what is the advantage of having a XIB for every view?

Comment: Well, assuming that each of your views takes up the entire iPhone screen, then it allows you to visually design each of your views separately and then load them individually as needed.  If you try to put everything in one xib file, then when that xib file gets loaded, all your views get loaded into memory as well.  Separating them out allows you to control that more efficiently

Comment: thanks for the help!  Now all I have to do it figure out how to make this idea work ;)  thanks again!

Comment: Can you help me with the code to do this?  I have the appdelegate with the NavController and one view. This works.  I then made a new class with a XIB which has a view and no controllers. Now what?  I guess starting at the IB as I dont have the appdelgate object I am not sure how to tie things together.  Then the code to call it.  I have spent all day going in circles.  Hope someone can help

Comment: For each UIView that you design, you will also want your own subclass of UIViewController (or UITableViewController).  This subclass that you create will be the File Owner for the xib that contains the UIView (click on File's Owner and in the Identity inspector change the class to your custom UIViewController subclass).  You can then load the nib this way: `MyVC *vc = [MyVC initWithNibName:NSStringFromClass([MyVC class]) bundle:nil];`